# on windows 8 error when gem install json --platform=ruby

Tags: ruby

After I install ruby 1.9.3
after I install devkit DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx
after I run ruby dk.rb init
after I run  ruby dk.rb install

when I run gem install json --platform=ruby
Then I see :

```
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
    ERROR:  Error installing json:
         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

         C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
            creating Makefile


    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
     Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Native Gem Extensions often require a C compiler, and other development tools.  My guess is that these tools are missing on your windows environment.  Are you executing this in a cygwin bash window?

Comment: devkit is the native compiler?. I have excecute this in dos.

Comment: Try `cc` or `gcc` at the dos prompt.  If not found, than you don't have a c compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try running
    `gem update --system 1.8.29`

and than
    `gem install json --platform=ruby`

It should work.